# Analytics Core Reporting API. Rows in different segments have same values

Tags: google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I probably have some misconception, so need help with understanding what is exactly wrong.

At analytics.google.com I have two segments they differ by event label but both are from the same event. In analytics interface difference between segments is visible:
[image: analytics.google.com interface screenshot]

When I'm trying to get this same data with tool like query explorer results are also different:
[image: ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ interface screenshot]

However, when I'm getting this data with reporting API v4, all values are the same between segments. I have also tried it with API v3, which resulted in similar outcomes.

Here is my code:

```
googleapis.analyticsreporting('v4').reports.batchGet({
  'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  "auth": oauth2Client,
  "resource":{
    reportRequests:[
      {
        "viewId": "ga:"+Meteor.settings.admin.googleAPI.viewID,
        "dateRanges":[{
          "startDate": '2016-07-01',
          "endDate": moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        }],
        "metrics": [{"expression":"ga:pageviews"},{"expression":"ga:avgtimeonpage"}],
        "dimensions": [{"name":"ga:pagepath"},{"name":"ga:segment"}],
        "segments": [{
          "dynamicSegment":
            {
              "name": "version_bw",
              "userSegment":
                {
                  "segmentFilters": [
                    {
                      "simpleSegment":
                        {
                          "orFiltersForSegment": [
                          {
                          "segmentFilterClauses": [
                            {
                            "dimensionFilter":
                              {
                                "dimensionName": "ga:eventAction",
                                "operator": "EXACT",
                                "expressions": ["set-visual-code"]
                              }
                            },{
                            "dimensionFilter":
                              {
                                "dimensionName": "ga:eventLabel",
                                "operator": "EXACT",
                                "expressions": ["bw"]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }]
                      }
                  }]
                }
          }
        },{
          "dynamicSegment":
            {
              "name": "version_color",
              "userSegment":
                {
                  "segmentFilters": [
                    {
                      "simpleSegment":
                        {
                        "orFiltersForSegment": [
                          {
                          "segmentFilterClauses": [
                            {
                            "dimensionFilter":
                              {
                                "dimensionName": "ga:eventAction",
                                "operator": "EXACT",
                                "expressions": ["set-visual-code"]
                              }
                            },{
                            "dimensionFilter":
                              {
                                "dimensionName": "ga:eventLabel",
                                "operator": "EXACT",
                                "expressions": ["color"]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }]
                      }
                  }]
                }
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }

}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('API Error: '+ err);
    return;
  }
  var rows = response.reports[0].data.rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(rows[i].dimensions);
    console.log(rows[i].metrics);
  }
});
```

Which results in following output:

```
I20160719-14:09:10.405(2)? [ '/', 'version_bw' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.406(2)? [ { values: [ '373', '174.11977715877438' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.406(2)? [ '/', 'version_color' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.407(2)? [ { values: [ '373', '174.11977715877438' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.407(2)? [ '/portfolio', 'version_bw' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.407(2)? [ { values: [ '468', '126.2876404494382' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.407(2)? [ '/portfolio', 'version_color' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.408(2)? [ { values: [ '468', '126.2876404494382' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.408(2)? [ '/portfolio/', 'version_bw' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.409(2)? [ { values: [ '22', '229.54545454545453' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.410(2)? [ '/portfolio/', 'version_color' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.410(2)? [ { values: [ '22', '229.54545454545453' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.410(2)? [ '/portfolio/graphics', 'version_bw' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.410(2)? [ { values: [ '84', '60.073170731707314' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.410(2)? [ '/portfolio/graphics', 'version_color' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.410(2)? [ { values: [ '84', '60.073170731707314' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.411(2)? [ '/portfolio/graphics/some-graphic', 'version_bw' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.411(2)? [ { values: [ '134', '42.02290076335878' ] } ]
I20160719-14:09:10.411(2)? [ '/portfolio/graphics/some-graphic', 'version_color' ]
I20160719-14:09:10.411(2)? [ { values: [ '134', '42.02290076335878' ] } ]
```